# Get and display file in iframe from another domain with ajax without direct link

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

On domain A I want to click a button and show the file in a pop-up iFrame.
The files are on domain B, not directly accessable and the files have generated names without extentions. All info about the file is stored in the database, with the right 'code' you get the file name, type etc. this part has to be done on domain B.

I think I have it close to working, I can see the file (or the data is tranferred), it is just not yet usable.

So on domain A I have this bit and showdoc() gets fired when clicking the button. The form contains the info needed to get the right file.

```
function showdoc() {
 $('#doc-modal').modal('show');
 var form = $('#downloadform')[0]; 
 var formData = new FormData(form);

 $.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function() {
    $("#loading").show();
  },
  complete: function() {
    $("#loading").hide();
  }
 });

 $.ajax({
  url: 'domain B',
  data: formData,
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
 }).done(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
 });
}
```

On domain B I process the post info, get the info from the database and have this (reused from the download script - this download script works without ajax and downloads the file directly, we want to show the file, not download it):

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
 header('Content-Type: ' . $type);
 header('Content-Disposition: inline');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$naam.'"');
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Expires: 0');
 header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
 header('Pragma: public');
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
 ob_clean();
 flush();
 readfile($file);
 exit;
}
```

At the moment, when I press the button I can see the XHR request is loading data and in the response headers I can see the expected filename etc. So I know the correct file was found and I assume send back.
[image: response header]

In the console I see this:

[image: console result]

On domain A I have an iframe with id 'dociframe'.
But I have no idea on how to get the file to display in there.
In this case the file is an PDF file, but it can also be a jpg or png.

Comment: An iframe has to point to a URL. I don't think you can embed other binary data in it. You'll  likely have more luck using a JS PDF viewer component in your page, instead of an iframe, I bet you can find a free one on the web